# how to get the content from a txt file into an array

Tags: php, arrays, file-get-contents

For some reason, i want to separate the keys and values from an associative array and read them from a txt file:

Below is what i did have

```
// translations
$lang = array(
    'All Articles' => 'Alle Artikelen',
    'Page' => 'Pagina',
    'from' => 'van'         
);
```

Now i want to change it like this:

```
$lang = array(
    file_get_contents("translations.txt"); // read the associative array
);
```

and `translations.txt` only contains:

```
'All Articles' => 'Alle Artikelen',
'Page' => 'Pagina',
'from' => 'van',
```

This does not work. How can i read out the key/value pairs when they are stored in an txt file like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible to get file content and directly assign to an array. You need to parse file, extract lines then extract key and value.

```
$str = file_get_contents("translations.txt");
$lang = [];
foreach (explode("\n", $str) as $line)
{
    if (strpos($line, '=>') === false)
    {
        continue;
    }

    list($key, $value) = explode('=>', $line);
    $lang[trim($key,'\' ')] = trim(trim($value), '\',');
}
```

By using `explode` extract lines based on line break(`\n`).

`if (strpos($line, '=>') === false)` is a control for avoid error on empty lines (usually end of file)

---

**Even beter use json file:**

translations.json

```
{"All Articles":"Alle Artikelen","Page":"Pagina","from":"van"}
```

And php code:

```
$lang = json_decode(file_get_contents(public_path('lang.json')), true);
var_dump($lang);
```

Comment: I didn't think about json but that is really a very good alternative! Thnx

Answer (score 1):

This could be dangerous. It will execute the code in the file.

```
eval(
  '$lang = array('.
    file_get_contents("translations.txt"). // read the associative array
  ');'
);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($lang);
```

Output:

```
 array(3) {
  ["All Articles"]=>
  string(14) "Alle Artikelen"
  ["Page"]=>
  string(6) "Pagina"
  ["from"]=>
  string(3) "van"
}
```

Comment: `eval` function can be dangerous